# XAF reports using stored procedures / SQL strings

Tags: c#, sql, devexpress, xaf

I kindly ask for your experienced advise on a matter.

I'm using DevExpress, trying to create XAF reports and sub-reports using SQL strings and stored procedures, without success.

Has anyone done this ever? Please let me know how to. I really like DevExpress but this is my Everest.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a similar question](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q458387) in the [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).

For DevExpress related questions, it is always best to ask there first.